# How to setup Android In-App Purchase for Currency?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-console-developer

I'm new in Android development, I'm trying to figure out how to setup In-App purchase to support currency.

I was reading the https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html

**And there is only two types if IAPs listed:**

Standard in-app products (one-time billing)

Subscriptions (recurring, automated billing)

I'm developing a game and I want user's to be able purchase packs of virtual money. How and where can I configure this settings?

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution of the problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/26166493/3395978 ))